# App crash when JSONArray is bigger than 261

Tags: java, android, json, broadcastreceiver, android-json

There is a `JSON` that include bus tickets information. We use volley to get data from web service. After, it get these bus information it send `adapter` with `broadcast`. Also, it occurs this error with some emulator devices.

```
 android.app.RemoteServiceException: can't deliver broadcast
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

I realized if JSONArray is bigger than 261 length, it don't run adapter. Then, I check JSONArray if it is bigger than 261 it send till 261 Why this problem happen? And how can solve this and send all of data to adapter?

Bus.java
       private void sendRequest(final String owner, final Map header)  {

```
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, MyConstants.URL + owner,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                //   Log.e("AAAA" + owner, response);
                try {

                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                    if (object.getString(MyConstants.SERVICE_STATUS).equals(MyConstants.SERVICE_RESPONSE_STATUS_NOTAVAILABLE)) {
                        // servisten gelen cevap not_available ise
                        //// owner
                        sendVoyagesErrorBroadcast(owner, MyConstants.ERROR_NOTAVAILABLE);
                    } else if (object.getString(MyConstants.SERVICE_STATUS).equals(MyConstants.SERVICE_RESPONSE_STATUS_SUCCESS)) {
                        // servisten gösterilebilecek bir sonuç geldiyse
                        JSONArray result = object.getJSONArray(MyConstants.SERVICE_RESULT);
                        if (result.length()>0) {
                            JSONArray resultGoing = result.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("going");
                            sendVoyagesArrayBroadcast(owner + MyConstants.DIRECTION_GOING, resultGoing);
                        }

// sendVoyagesArrayBroadcast
private void sendVoyagesArrayBroadcast(String target, JSONArray resultArray_) {

       JSONArray resultArray = new JSONArray();
        if (resultArray_.length()>261)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 261; i++) {
                try {
                    resultArray.put(resultArray_.get(i));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Log.e("resultArray","");

        }
        else
            resultArray=resultArray_; 



        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(BROADCAST_TAG + target);

        intent.putExtra("data", resultArray.toString());
    /*if(!target.contains("bus2")){
     Log.e("sendSuccessBroadcast",target);
     intent.putExtra("data", resultArray.toString());
     }*/

        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to `bundle`, `bundle` sizes are limited to pass data. Use `EventBus` if you want to pass data without a wire, it can handle enough data transfer

Comment: I did with `EventBus`. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Use pagination. You can do this in two ways:

1. Locally in your app
2. With a Web Service

I suggest use of option 2. If not, then load 10-20 items at a time for this.

Comment: What do you think about Lakhwinder Singh's answer?

Comment: I dont use eventbus but yes bundle have size limit around 500kb and using them is bit cumbersome, if you are using list then go for pagination and design accordingly. Also i would suggest to use retrofit. It will make your life easy.

Comment: ok, thanks for your helping. I know Retrofit is better. But in this project the developer before than me he use volley. And I continue with it. I don't want change it now for this project.